Is $\int_{M_1\sqcup M_2}\omega= \int_{M_1}i_1^*\omega + \int_{M_2}i_2^*\omega$?
If I want to compute the integral of a smooth compactly supported differential form over a disconnected oriented smooth manifold $M=M_1\sqcup M_2$ with two connected components $M_1$ and $M_2$, is it possible to compute the integral on each component and add the results to get an integral on whole of $M$? More precisely, if $i_1,i_2$ denotes the inclusions from $M_1$ and $M_2$ respectively in to $M$, and if $\omega$ is a top form on $M$ do we have the equality
$$\int_{M_1\sqcup M_2}\omega= \int_{M_1}i_1^*\omega + \int_{M_2}i_2^*\omega.$$
Note that both $M_1$ and $M_2$ can be given an orientation inherited from $M$.
I am new to integrals on manifolds and this question comes to me naturally. I have a strong feeling that this is true but I don’t see any books to have this result written down. If anyone can help me clarify this I will be very grateful.

As long as you put the correct orientations on $M_1\cup M_2$ and $M_1$ and $M_2$, then yes the statement is correct (once you fix the typo in the second term to $\int_{M_2}\iota_2^*\omega$, and once you add the obvious integrability hypotheses on $\omega$). For a proof, you just unwind how integrals over manifolds are defined.

Yes that $\int_{M_1}i_1^*\omega$ in the second term is a typo.ill fix it. What do you mean by putting correct orientations on $M_1\sqcup M_2$?

I have edited the question. Please see if it is correct now.

@Uncool now the way you wrote it is correct. The point is if you start with an orientation on $M$ then you must use the induced orientations on both $M_1,M_2$ as open subsets for your statement to be true. Conversely if you start with orientations for both $M_1,M_2$, then there is a unique orientation (out of the four total possible choices) such that it induces the given orientations, and thus makes the equation true.
